# Formal group law of unoriented cobordism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cobordism, reference-request

It is well known that the formal group law $F_U$ of complex cobordism, expressing the Euler class of a tensor product of complex line bundles, is universal.

Also, the formal group law $F_O$ of unoriented cobordism, expressing the Euler class of a tensor product of real line bundles, is universal among formal group laws in characteristic 2 with the property that $F(X,X)=0$.

There is a nice description of $F_U$ in terms of manifold generators, due to Buchstaber:
$$
F_U(X,Y) = \frac{\sum_{i,j\geq 0} [H_{ij}]\;X^iY^j}{\left(\sum_{r\geq 0}[\mathbb{C}P^r] X^r\right) \left(\sum_{s\geq 0}[\mathbb{C}P^s] Y^s\right)}
$$
where the $H_{ij}$ are Milnor hypersurfaces. Here I am quoting [this page](http://www.map.him.uni-bonn.de/Formal_group_laws_and_genera#Formal_group_law_of_geometric_cobordisms).

Is there a similar description of $F_O(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you just get the same formula, with $\mathbb{C}P^k$ replaced by $\mathbb{R}P^k$, and $H_{ij}$ replaced by the corresponding real hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}P^i\times\mathbb{R}P^j$.  The proof of the equivalent formula
$$ \left(\sum [\mathbb{R}P^r]\;X^r\right)
   \left(\sum [\mathbb{R}P^s]\;Y^s\right) 
   F_O(X,Y) = 
   \sum H_{ij} X^i Y^j
$$
is quite direct and geometric.  (I might come back and write more tomorrow.)

Comment: Hi Neil. You were right, of course. As I've just got round to checking, the proof on the page I linked goes through $\mathbb{R}$ replacing $\mathbb{C}$.